# Scala instantiation from manifests in nested generic code

Tags: scala, instantiation, type-erasure, nested-generics

If I could figure out how to "attach manifests back the generic call stack" (as Joshua writes about in section 7.2.2 of "Scala in Depth"), would that enable me to instantiate B along those lines?:

```
def m1[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = m.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]

class A {
  def m2[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = m.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T]
  def inA() {
    m1[A]
    m2[A]
    m2[B] // Doesn't work...
  }
  class B
}

m1[A]
val a = new A
a.m2[A]
a.inA() // boom
```

Or do I need some view bound?

Comment: What are you on about? What is the error? What is the question?

Comment: How can I instantiate a nested class from the type alone? Is that a better question? Forgot: I'm on Scala 2.10.0-M1. The error is: java.lang.InstantiationException: A$B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate the inner class `B` like this, because the constructor of such inner classes secretly takes a reference to an object of the outer class. `newInstance` can only be called on classes that have a zero-argument constructor.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another way around - builder pattern or something?

Comment: If you have a case where it makes sense that you instantiate an inner class without the outer instance, than it isn't truly an inner class.

Comment: B will belong to an A instance. It's just that I would like to be able to create B with a method call of another object like `obj.as[B]` instead of `obj.as(new B)`. The syntactic sugar should defer B creation to a superclass. As you might have guessed, B is a Role in a DCI Context, and conceptually we don't want the impression of a separate Role object, only a Data object playing a Role - a Role Player. That's why I want to "hide" the Role creation.